# Using Apache UIMA to Build NLP Operation Pipeline

Tags: java, apache, nlp, uima

I am new to Apache UIMA and I am trying to build a NLP pipeline using Apache UIMA. When user upload the document (i.e. pdf, words) I want to extract the data using Tika Annotator. I am able to extract Text from pdf and other documents using APache Tika but how to write Annotator for this and how to pass the output of one annotator as input to other annotator. I went through apache UIMA site but was not able to capture much from the site so that I can use it in my project.

for example will be having Tika Annotator to extract Text and then perform Tokenization in TokenAnnotator using the Output Tika Annotator and then use  TokenAnnotator Output as Input to POS Annotator

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi Rana, I think it might help, if you could provide more details regarding the actual use case(s). Even if you have tokenized and POS-tagged the texts, they wouldn't be much use. What is it that you are trying to accomplish in the end?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to Build a Pipeline in UIMA. The actual use case goes like this (1) You upload some document might be pdf, word document (2) You use Apache Tika Annotator to extract the content from the document (3) Using the output of Tika Annotator to Perform White space Tokenization (4) Perform POS Tagging.

Comment: That much I understood. But once you have the texts tokenized and POS tagged, what would be the next steps? Because usually, these two steps are preliminary steps in an NLP pipeline (unless optimizating the tokenization and tagging is what you're working on, but it didn't sounld like it).

Comment: Martin you can perform topic modelling, text classification, sentiment analysis and also do search and oraganize using apache solr

Answer (score 2):

UIMA uses the CAS (or JCas if you are doing Java) as the "shared context" between annotators.

So in your case, you would define an UIMA Annotator pipeline as a sequence of (TikaAnnotator, SentenceAnnotator, POSAnnotator), then call this pipeline with the PDF or Word document as the input. You might have to serialize the PDF/Word bytes as base64 and decode it back because CAS expects a (ascii?) string in documentText. The TikaAnnotator will read the PDF/Word bytes using CAS.getDocumentText(), parse out the text and write the text out to the AnnotationIndex with a specific type of Annotation class (say TikaAnnotation).

The SentenceAnnotator will then pull out the text from the Annotation index using the TikaAnnotation.class key, and tokenize it into multiple SentenceAnnotations, which are again written out to the AnnotationIndex in the CAS.

Finally the POSAnnotator will pull out the SentenceAnnotations by class name and for each one, write out multiple POS annotations back into the index.

I have some code here which might help illustrate the above. There are also many similar examples on the web, and IIRC UIMA has some excellent documentation also.

http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2011/04/uima-sentence-annotator-using-opennlp.html
http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2011/08/uima-noun-phrase-pos-annotator-using.html

UIMA depends on a combination of XML configuration and Java code, and I found that the system became a pain to maintain after a while. For a subsequent (work related) project (based on the POC described in the blog post) I chose [UIMAFit](https://uima.apache.org/uimafit.html) instead.